# Flutter provider patter not effecting UI changes on List content change widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

the UI gets updated once i change a value directly, 
but not when I change the value of an Item in the List
Could someone have encountered this challenge before?
Please explain why this could be happening.
What alternatives could be availble ?

```
 class Item {
      int itemQty;
      final double itemPrice;
      final double itemDiscount;

      Item({
        this.itemDiscount,
        this.itemQty,
        this.itemPrice,
      });

      Map<String, Object> toJson() {
        return {
          'itemPrice': itemPrice,
          'itemQun': itemQty,
          'itemDiscount': itemDiscount,
        };
      }    
        class Home extends StatelessWidget {    
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
          return Scaffold(
              body:Container(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle,
                                            color: Colors.amber.shade500),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          if (model.quantity >
                                              0) {
                                            model.quantity--;
                                          }
                                        },
                                      ),

                                      new IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle,
                                            color: Colors.amber.shade500),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          if (itemList[ind].itemQty >
                                              0) {
                                            Provider.of<MakanikaModel>(
                                              context,
                                            ).requestItems[ind].itemQty--;
                                          }
                                        },
                                      )
                  ],
                ),            
              ),  
            );
          }
        }
```

Comment: You need a setState somewhere.

Comment: Could you show the implementation of the MakanikaModel class?

Comment: ```class MakanikaModel with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Item> _requestItems = List<Item>();
  int _quantity = 0;

  set quantity(newValue) {
    _quantity = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set requestItems(newValue) {
    _requestItems = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  //getters
  List<Item> get requestItems => _requestItems;
  int get quantity => _quantity;
}```

Comment: @RémiRousselet am using provider set state is inbuild with provider.